# width of website not shrinking on mobile devices correctly, meta not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, width, shrink

So Im building a website which looks totally fine on computer browsers, but when opened in mobile browsers especially in Safari on iPhone the width doesnt shrink as it supposed to and is just huge though and you cant even zoom out, even though I tried to use all of the meta tags from

```html
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">
```

to

```html
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=1300, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

Doesn anyone know how to fit it?

Here's my html and css code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #331f0e;
  background-image: url(layout/background.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0; 
  width: 1300px;
}

#header {
  height: 667px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1300px;
}

#logo {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#stories {
  font-size: 32pt;
  left: 215px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 615px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#diary {
  font-size: 32pt;
  left: 437px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 615px;
  z-index: 100;
}


#home {
  font-size: 40pt;
  left: 616px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 609px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#author {
  font-size: 32pt;
  left: 829px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 615px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#web {
  font-size: 32pt;
  left: 1048px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 615px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk" class="no-js"> 


  <head>      

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />   

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

      <div id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="layout/header.png" border="0">
        <a href="stories.html" id="stories" target="update">Stories</a>
        <a href="diary.php" id="diary" target="update">Diary</a>
        <a href="home.html" id="home" target="update">Home</a>
        <a href="author.html" id="author" target="update">Author</a>
        <a href="web.html" id="web" target="update">Web</a>
      </div>

      <br><br><br>

    </div>
```

Comment: Why can't you align your code even when there's an option?

Comment: I guess this is the problem `#wrapper {width: 1300px;}`

Comment: That was only one of the problems. This is completely hardcoded for browsers. There are a bunch of other numbers that need to be changed as well. I pointed this out in my answer